# Warning: Cannot modify header information - How to resolve this issue?

Tags: plugin-development

What is the wrong with this code. I am always getting the error like:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/krishnas/Documents/wordpress/wp-admin/menu-header.php:91) in
>   /home/krishnas/Documents/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
>   866

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $basedir = $upload_dir['basedir'];
        $baseurl = $upload_dir['baseurl'];
        $filename = "products_".date('YmdHis').".xls";
        $fp = fopen($basedir.'/'.$filename,'wr');
        fwrite($fp,$content_final);
        $excell_file = $baseurl.'/'.$filename;
        //echo $basedir;
        //echo $baseurl;
        //exit;
        //exit;
        wp_redirect($excell_file);exit;}}?>
```

Comment: where is this code? wp_redirect has to be used before any data is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is no blank space or any extra character after ?> of PHP. It's seen that such errors are usually causes by extra characters after ?> at the end of file. Please check both the files mentioned in the error code. Let us know if this resolves your error.

Comment: If `?>` comes at the end of the file you can just leave it out too.

Answer (score 0):

please review information in [this WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F) for solving "headers already sent" warnings.